# Tag synonym: “grrm” to “george-r-r-martin”

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two author tags like this:

- [grrm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grrm) (3 questions, fairly new). All three are related to GoT/ASOIAF.
- [george-r-r-martin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-r-r-martin) (190 questions)

I don’t have the necessary rep to suggest the tag synonym, but this seems like an obvious one.

Comment: 2500 rep should suffice to suggest tag synonyms.

Comment: I'd like to see this tag synonym implemented. GRRM and George R. R. Martin are completely synonymous; I think GRRM is a commonly accepted acronym that has enough currency among ASOIAF readers to be recognised. I doubt this would create any uncertainty among site users; the synonym is useful only to people who already know about the [george-r-r-martin] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've deleted all the [grrm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grrm) instances, so that tag will be destroyed on next auto-cleanup.  There's absolutely no need for it.

A tag synonym would make sense if it re-appears.  As it was, the tag was created by a single user, and hopefully he'll get the hint and not add them to any more questions.

Comment: Hit me up if it shows up again.

Comment: Looks like it showed up again, so I approved the synonym suggestion someone had made for it.